# How to add a period at the end of the sequence in stead of a comma?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() {
    int fib[10];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << fib[i] << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34,

But I want to replace the comma after 34 with a period. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the print for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << fib[i] << (i < (10 - 1) ? ", " : ".");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to handle it by printing the comma *before* the number rather than after it (except for the first number in the list) like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i > 0) cout << ", ";
    cout << fib[i];
}
cout << ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

Branchless version:

```
const char* sep = "";
for (auto e : fib) {
    std::cout << sep << e;
    sep = ", ";
}
std::cout << ".";
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17669c453f4c9bcb)